# How to access raw video data from CSI camera?

Tags: video, c, camera

I'm developing an augmented reality sort of app for the Pi, but I need access to the video data (pixel data) to tweak things programmatically from a C program, then display the modified frames.

How does one go about accessing the video data from the Pi's CSI camera?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the source code for raspivid. It sets up a pipeline to the H.264 encoder. If you want the raw frames, you should be able to remove the pipeline and supply a callback for the camera hardware to pass the buffers into.